# Importar base datos en un schema POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

Tengo el siguiente comando donde he creado una copia de la estructura de una base de datos en `mysql` a `postgres` pero al momento de importarla, esta me la importa en el schemas `public` pero me gustaria poder que me la importara en un schemas especifico.

Aqui el comando.

```
psql -f /home/linux/backup-postgresql.sql -U username db
```

Soy nuevo en postgres. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

crea el esquema con el nombre que deseas y luego a esa base de datos le seteas el search_path con el nuevo esquema.

Por ejemplo:

```
Create schema nuevo;
Set search_path = nuevo; 
--esto es en esta sesión
\i home/linux/backup-postgresql.sql
```

O

```
Alter database db set search_path= nuevo; 
-- esto es para siempre en esta base de datos
```

Y luego cargas el script psql -f /home/linux/backup-postgresql.sql -U username db

Todo lo que crees irá al esquema nuevo si quieres volver a cambiarlo vuelves a ejecutar el mismo procedimiento

Saludos